# Does the power Beast Friend work for, say, part of a Coral Reef?

Tags: savage-worlds

Say you were an underwater creature with Beast Friend. Would it be reasonable to use the power to control part of a coral reef and all the small creatures in the area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is reasonable.  Treat the animals from the reef as a swarm.  There's a mention of a piranha swarm in the Swarm section (Chapter 7 of the Explorer's Edition).